# HTML responsive email width issue in Outlook

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, outlook, html-email

I'm creating a responsive email template based off of [this](http://zurb.com/playground/projects/responsive-email-templates/basic.html).

I've got it working how I want it in Gmail, Yahoo, Outlook.com etc. and most phones but I can't work out why Outlook on desktop doesn't like it. I want the width of the email not to stretch further than 662px.

Screenshots:

[Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBbZ1.png)
[Apple Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbNk1.png) (how I want it to look)

Here's the code, I'm using [MailChimps CSS inliner tool](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css) before I send tests every time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- If you delete this tag, the sky will fall on your head -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>XXX</title>

<style type="text/css">
/* ------------------------------------- 
        GLOBAL 
------------------------------------- */
* { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
* { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
}
.collapse {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; 
    width: 100%!important; 
    height: 100%;
}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        ELEMENTS 
------------------------------------- */
a { color: #2BA6CB;}

p.callout {
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#ECF8FF;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.callout a {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #2BA6CB;
}

table.social {
/*  padding:15px; */
    background-color: #ebebeb;

}

/* ------------------------------------- 
        HEADER 
------------------------------------- */
table.head-wrap { width: 100%;}

.header.container table td.logo { padding: 15px; }
.header.container table td.label { padding: 15px; padding-left:0px;}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        BODY 
------------------------------------- */
table.body-wrap { width: 100%;}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        FOOTER 
------------------------------------- */
table.footer-wrap { width: 100%;    clear:both!important;
}
.footer-wrap .container td.content  p { border-top: 1px solid rgb(215,215,215); padding-top:15px;}
.footer-wrap .container td.content p {
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight: bold;

}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        TYPOGRAPHY 
------------------------------------- */
h3 {
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom:15px; color:#000;
}

h3 { font-weight:500; font-size: 60px; color:red;}

.collapse { margin:0!important;}

p, ul { 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size:14px; 
    line-height:1.6;
    color: #5B6063;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------- 
        RESPONSIVENESS
        Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. 
------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
.container {
    display:block!important;
    max-width:662px!important;
    margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
    clear:both!important;
}

/* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
.content {
    padding:15px;
    max-width:662px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block; 
}

.mainBg {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/643x638');
    /*background-image: url('XXX_BG_2.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;*/
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.mainOverlay {
    width: 375px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #cccccc;
}

.overlayText {
    width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */
.content table { width: 100%; }


/* Odds and ends */
.column {
    width: 300px;
    float:left;
}
.column tr td { padding: 15px; }
.column-wrap { 
    padding:0!important; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    max-width:662px!important;
}
.column table { width:100%;}

/* Be sure to place a .clear element after each set of columns, just to be safe */
.clear { display: block; clear: both; }

/* ------------------------------------------- 
        PHONE
        For clients that support media queries.
        Nothing fancy. 
-------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 662px) {

    a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}

    div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}

    table.social div[class="column"] {
        width:auto!important;
    }

    p, ul { 
        margin-bottom: 10px!important; 
        font-weight: normal!important; 
        font-size:11px!important; 
        line-height:1.6!important;
    }

    .mainOverlay {
        max-width: 220px!important;
        margin:0 auto!important;
        background-color: #FFFFFF!important;
        border-style: solid!important;
        border-width: 1px!important;
        border-color: #cccccc!important;
    }


    .overlayText {
        width: 170px!important;
        margin:0 auto!important;
    }

    h3 { 
        font-weight:500!important; 
        font-size: 27px!important; 
        color:red!important;
    }

}
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<!-- HEADER -->
<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="header container">

                <div class="content">
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/240x40" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/69x18" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/94x18" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/73x18" /></a>
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/86x18" /></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

        </td>
        <td class="header container">

                <div class="content">
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" style="border-top: solid #cccccc 1px; border-bottom: solid #cccccc 1px; font-size:11px;"><span style="color: rgb(44,147,221)">FREE SHIPPING</span> ON ORDERS OVER XXX</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /HEADER -->


<!-- BODY -->
<table class="body-wrap">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

            <div class="content">
                <div class="mainBg">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <br />
                                <h3 align="center">JOYEUX ANNIVERSAIRE!</h3>
                                        Dear XXXX,
                                        <br /><br />
                                                <span style="font-weight:bold;">Happy Birthday from XXX!</span>
                                                <br /><br />
                                                To celebrate your special day, 
                                                we’re giving you <span style="color: red">$XX</span> to spend 
                                                at our online store.
                                                <br /><br />
                                                Simply enter the code 
                                                <span style="color: red">XXX</span> at checkout.
                                                <br /><br />
                                                Your offer is valid for the next XX days. 
                                                Enjoy!
                                                <br /><br />
                                                <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/203x38" /></a>
                                                <p>&nbsp;</p>

                                <span class="clear"></span> 


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>  
            </div>

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /BODY -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<table class="footer-wrap">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container">

                <div class="content">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <p>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x16" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/21x37" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/23x37" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/21x37" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/22x37" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/22x37" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/22x37" /></a>
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/110x37" /></a>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /FOOTER -->

</body>
</html>
```

Inlined:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
<title style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">XXX</title>



</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;height: 100%;width: 100%;">

<!-- HEADER -->
<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width: 100%;">
    <tr style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <td style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"></td>
        <td class="header container" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;display: block;max-width: 662px;clear: both;">

                <div class="content" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 15px;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 662px;display: block;">
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width: 100%;">
                        <tr style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                            <td style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/240x40" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/69x18" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/94x18" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/73x18" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/86x18" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

        </td>
        <td class="header container" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;display: block;max-width: 662px;clear: both;">

                <div class="content" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 15px;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 662px;display: block;">
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width: 100%;">
                    <tr style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                        <td align="center" style="border-top: solid #cccccc 1px;border-bottom: solid #cccccc 1px;font-size: 11px;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><span style="color: rgb(44,147,221);margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">FREE SHIPPING</span> ON ORDERS OVER XXX</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>

        </td>
        <td style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /HEADER -->


<!-- BODY -->
<table class="body-wrap" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width: 100%;">
    <tr style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <td style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"></td>
        <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;display: block;max-width: 662px;clear: both;">

            <div class="content" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 15px;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 662px;display: block;">
                <div class="mainBg" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;background-color: #CCCCCC;background-image: url(http://placehold.it/643x638);background-repeat: repeat-x;">
                    <table style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width: 100%;">
                        <tr style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                            <td align="center" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                <br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                <h3 align="center" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;HelveticaNeue-Light&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue Light&quot;, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, &quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, sans-serif;line-height: 1.1;margin-bottom: 15px;color: red;font-weight: 500;font-size: 60px;">JOYEUX ANNIVERSAIRE!</h3>
                                        Dear XXXX,
                                        <br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                                <span style="font-weight: bold;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">Happy Birthday from XXX!</span>
                                                <br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                                To celebrate your special day, 
                                                we’re giving you <span style="color: red;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">$XX</span> to spend 
                                                at our online store.
                                                <br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                                Simply enter the code 
                                                <span style="color: red;margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">XXX</span> at checkout.
                                                <br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                                Your offer is valid for the next XX days. 
                                                Enjoy!
                                                <br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"><br style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                                <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/203x38" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                                <p style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin-bottom: 10px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.6;color: #5B6063;">&nbsp;</p>

                                <span class="clear" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;display: block;clear: both;"></span>   


                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>  
            </div>

        </td>
        <td style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /BODY -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<table class="footer-wrap" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width: 100%;clear: both;">
    <tr style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
        <td style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"></td>
        <td class="container" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;display: block;max-width: 662px;clear: both;">

                <div class="content" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 15px;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 662px;display: block;">
                    <table style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;width: 100%;">
                        <tr style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                            <td align="center" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                                <p style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;margin-bottom: 10px;font-weight: bold;font-size: 14px;line-height: 1.6;color: #5B6063;">
                                    <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/125x16" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                    <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/21x37" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                    <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/23x37" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                    <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/21x37" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                    <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/22x37" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                    <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/22x37" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                    <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/22x37" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                    <a href="#" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #2BA6CB;"><img src="http://placehold.it/110x37" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;max-width: 100%;"></a>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

        </td>
        <td style="margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, &quot;Helvetica&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- /FOOTER -->

</body>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT: Added screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a center alignment on your container and it will resolve your problem.

The code I'm pasting also suggests some additional improvements you can leverage if you like.

```
<center>
    <table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">    
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>YOUR EMAIL CONTENT NESTED HERE</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

Comment: This seemed to fix the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on max-width for Outlook. Check [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), a great resource that shows which email clients accept different css properties. If you want something to look good on outlook, I would be sure and use [Zurb's boilerplate css and html](http://zurb.com/ink/docs.php). It looks like that is what you're using, but stick as close as possible. You have to be really careful to write a cross-client email. It takes a lot of time and debugging.

EDIT: Also, it's generally recommended to not exceed 600px in width for an email template.

Comment: Thanks, what's really frustrating is that their template limits the width to 600px when I tested it but mine doesn't... feels like it could be something really obvious.

Comment: I would honestly try to use their template if possible. Keeping the width at 600px or less is highly recommended. I've written a lot of email templates and sticking to their framework, but modifying it to your needs, always ends up working best.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is actually a fluid max width technique, not a responsive one (although you need to leverage media queries to do this for Outlook '11).

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483059/responsive-order-confirmation-emails-for-mobile-devices/20497625#20497625). Just swap out the inner table with your own and change the width from 600 to whatever you need it to be.