# Html charts in email without using javascript

Tags: html, email, charts, newsletter

I'm looking for nice charts for my newsletter. Since javascript is not email friendly I need an html only solution.

I'll send email once a month with statistics of user's performance and stuff done during the month.

So what do you think is the best solution? 
Can I found some nice basic html charts where I can change little in my back-end with user's data?

I know with JS it would be easy, but is not my case.
I'll send both to mobile and desktop.

Thank you very very much!!

Comment: this might be useful, https://github.com/ryanrolds/quiche

Comment: you may use https://developers.google.com/chart/image/ as easy as `<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World" />`

Comment: https://image-charts.com/chart was built just for that  (and it's a drop-in replacement for the deprecated Google Image-Charts)... and it has support for gif animation as well 

Comment: If you use Chart.js for your Javascript charts, have a look at https://quickchart.io/.  It's an open source web service that converts Chart.js to an image embeddable in email.

Comment: Hi, a bit late, but you can also use https://charttt.com to generate image charts that can be embedded into emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any scripting language you want pre-send, but the email itself needs to be pure html. The only way you can change its contents after send, is if you link it to a hosted image, and you swap out that image.

With that being said, if you are after a html email example with a chart to get started, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483059/responsive-order-confirmation-emails-for-mobile-devices/20497625#20497625). It is a fluid template which is the most widely supported technique for mobile, web and desktop browsers.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the game here, but my team at Ramen recently spun out some internal functionality into a standalone product that does just this: https://ChartURL.com

You can generate charts on the fly using an "Encrypted URL" scheme, or you can send us huge amounts of data and return a Short URL that'll resolve to an image. These URLs can be used in web apps & mobile apps, but the original intent was email charts so I hope this helps!

Comment: Very interesting concept, I'll give it a try!

Comment: seems really cool :)

Comment: Not working anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against trying to attach js/css/html based charts, you will run into a lot of issues. I've wrote a tutorial on generating charts as images and attaching to emails here: http://www.sqldashboards.com/b/send-email-with-graphs/ Basically you

1. Configure mutt to allow sending email
2. Generate charts at the command line.
3. Send an email, with attachments using mutt

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply use raw `HTML` to get charts. It is simply not possible, just got to use a scripting language to do so, `HTML` isn't one.

If you are willing to use `CSS3` to make your chart a reality, I suggest you to check out this good article: http://www.ssiddique.info/dynamic-chart-in-css.html

Comment: Yes I know, that's why my idea was doing the script part in the back end and send the email already formatted showing charts made only with html stuff. Anyway, how could I include in a email script  accepted by email clients ?

Comment: Which languages are you willing to use?

Comment: Any language, what matters is that the script can be read by clients. For example Gmail does not accept javascript, so I can't use it for charts.

Comment: I now understand clearier your question. You got to use plain html5 with css3, check out the link I gave you: http://www.ssiddique.info/dynamic-chart-in-css.html

Answer (score 1):

The best idea would be to generate images and send them, as you can't use pure html to make a chart.

Comment: Images are a good idea, but I'm afraid it would be heavy in the processing and in the email load

Comment: @gigilatrottola I'm afraid it's probably the only way to accomplish this. If needs be you could make it a GIF format, which would be very small in size and shouldn't affect the processing and size of the email as much as normal pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an animated gif.

http://www.emailology.org/ might have something for you.