# How to incorporate different sized logo images into image tag at runtime

Tags: html, css, image, email, dynamic

In Email template design, we have to add sender logo, which is of three different shapes rectangular, square and vertical.

1. rectangular width around 102*18
2. square 43*40
3. vertical 18*43

The images gets loaded from backend at runtime.
The provided images for logos are High resolution. I tried to resize images and without fixed width fixed width/ height on img tag. It worked but the display quality is very poor as it lost some pixels while resizing.
I can not give fixed width i.e. 102px as other images(square and vertical) gets stretched.

`<table><tr><td><img src="abc.net/{{logoid}}"></td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

> In your case you need to set `object-fit` property in `img` so that
>   what ever its dimension is it can fit inside your layout that suits
>   best, `object-fit: contain` worked best in you scenario as you upload
>   logo so it need to be fully display.

*NOTE: you need some specific `height` just for the layout it wont effect your image dimension*

Here is an example

```css
.cover {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="original-image">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg" width="242" height="363" />
</figure>

<figure class="cropped-image">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OrtT.jpg" width="242" height="363" class="cover" />
</figure>
```

There's a polyfill for IE: https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit

Comment: Thanks, It works on other clients except Outlook desktop application. Outlook desktop needs inline width to display properly. 
How to add responsive images on outlook desktop application?

Comment: For image responsive on any device you need to set its `width` to `100%` for further detail please [view this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391855/how-to-make-an-image-responsive-in-html-email-regardless-of-image-size)