# Is there a way to embed an image into an email so that it fills the whole page?

Tags: html, image, email, embedded-resource

Before I start, I will clarify that I don't write code myself (I'm a cretive designer), but I do know how it works to a basic degree. However, I'm asking because this is extremely important and I'm struggling with it terribly.

I need to craft an email with a png image I've already made, and it needs to be the whole email. It should fill the whole email-viewer page on any device that opens the email, like this:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDXuA.png.)

-(this is an approximation - the closest I could get to my goal. It doesn't appear like this on desktop view though, and I can't have the space above it)

I'm using the mailchimp builder but it's not allowing me to make an image the whole page, so I thought I could switch to HTML to overwrite it as I was getting desperate.

I know it *is* a bit of a stretch but I was wondering if anyone could show me the couple lines of code I could copy-paste to the HTML builder? All I need is for the image to fill the whole page and be embedded into the email.

Thank you!

Comment: See if this helps :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29391855/how-to-make-an-image-responsive-in-html-email-regardless-of-image-size/29803170

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, that sounds possible. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score -2):

That's really easy!

First, Inspect the email that you are sending. Like This ⬇

[image]

Then, right click, press "Edit as HTML" and add this ⬇

[image]

(I'm sorry I don't know how to do it on mailchimp, it should work the same)

Comment: For the second screenshot, please embed code as text, and format it using Markdown.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, could you explain to me how exactly do I do that?

Comment: You can just paste it as text, but then use ``backticks`` to demarcate code.  There is also a formatting toolbar in the post editor that includes a button that will do that for you.