# Responsive Email Media Query Not Working When Resizing Browser

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm having trouble with my @media query. When I resize the browser (chrome) it doesn't shrink. I've tried a couple solutions now and can't get it to work. I'm sure it's a simple user error but from the different articles and blogs I have read it seems this is the logical solution and should work.

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="body-table">
          <tbody>
            <tr align="center">
              <td width="100%" class="container" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="100">
```

And the media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
        *[class="container"] { width:100% !important;}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.container` table not shrink because it parent is fixed width. So instead of fixed width parent we will add width to the `td` that hold your main table.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td width="600">
            <table class="container" width="100%" style="background: peru;">
                <tr>
                    <td>This will shrink when width less than 600 pixels.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

You can find a more detail answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426072/is-there-an-equivalent-of-css-max-width-that-works-in-html-emails) or this pen [here](https://codepen.io/khanhvdv/pen/GvmJaY) and I highly recommended you to check out this [guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) to see which CSS style each email clients support.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you have a fixed width in your table.
So try changing your fixed width to percentage.
Like this

```
width="80%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
width="600"
```

to

```
width="50%"
```