# A max-width alternative

Tags: html, css

I am working in an environment (kindlegen) that doesn't support `max-width`. I have a `div` that should be of a specified width unless the viewport shrink, in which case it should shrink with it. `max-width` is what I need, but it is not supported.

Is there a HTML/CSS-only workaround? Any clever idea that can achieve the same effect?

*(Javascript is not supported either.)*

```css
.outside {
  width: 14em; /* will change with window (100vw) */
  background: orange;
}

.inside {
  width: 24em; /* max-width will do it */
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <p>Main container</p>
  <div class="inside">Inside text that should never be wider than its parent.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That depends on what the environment will support. The first thing that came to mind was a media query, but may I guess that's not supported either?

Comment: This answer might be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24499931/5358917. Try whether you can apply the same to your scenario.

Comment: Another possibility I thought of was to to put the `inside` block in a container with `padding-right: calc(100vw - 24em);` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)) but I suppose `calc` isn't usable either. Then @Kavindra's link looks the most promising.

Comment: What about using span in place of div or changing the display property???

Comment: What exactly do you propose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an equivalent of CSS max-width that works in HTML emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426072/is-there-an-equivalent-of-css-max-width-that-works-in-html-emails)

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do something like this, or am I missing something?

```css
.outside {
  width: 100%; 
  background: orange;
}

.inside {
  width: 80%; 
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <p>Main container</p>
</div>

<div class="inside">
  <p>Inside text that should never be wider than its parent.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the RED div will be always smaller than its parent (ORANGE). Using `max-width` only set a limit, thus RED will be as wide as its parent until and unless that limit is reached. But in your example, RED will be *always* 80% of its parent. Again, `max-width` is the solution, it is just not supported in the environment I am working on, hence the “alternative” part on my original question. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I would definitely check out the fiddle linked previously then if you want this process to be conditional: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426072/is-there-an-equivalent-of-css-max-width-that-works-in-html-emails

Comment: Thanks. The second comment of the main question already references this link.

Comment: Exactly why I said "linked previously" - best of luck! :)